# Default code collapse on demand in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to force IntelliJ to fold code using default settings? Jet Brains [documentation says](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/code-folding-2.html) that it is performed only once, when the file is opened **for the first** time.

Comment: You mean something like this: Ctrl+Shift+Minus ?

Comment: I need to follow Ctrl+Shift+Minus with Ctrl+Shift+Plus, but still, better than nothing.